# IOptionsMonitor not working inside docker container

Tags: docker, .net-core

Is it possible to detect appsettings changes with `IOptionsMonitor` when running a (C# .NET 5) web application inside docker?

I have an application that, when run locally, fires the `OnChange` event of my options monitor whenever I touch the `appsettings.json` file. However, the event is not fired when running the application in a docker container with mounted appsettings file.

Answer (score 1):

Docker do not send change notifications to file provider by default, but you can
use environment variable `ENV DOTNET_USE_POLLING_FILE_WATCHER=true`.

> Some file systems, such as Docker containers and network shares, may
> not reliably send change notifications. Set the
> DOTNET_USE_POLLING_FILE_WATCHER environment variable to 1 or true to
> poll the file system for changes every four seconds (not
> configurable).

You can read more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/file-providers?view=aspnetcore-6.0#watch-for-changes